# How to make a Spring Boot project dependency use H2 database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a Spring Boot project (MAIN) which in turn depends on a  (DAL) dependency.

DAL is where every Entity, Repository, Projection and Spring Data JPA related configurations are.

Now, MAIN project is a scheduler, and I need to make some integration tests over it. As always I want to use H2 database for the job in hands.

I have the H2 configuration under /test/resources/application.properties and this configuration have always worked if the JPA related classes were in the same project.

But in this specific case what is happening is that the H2 configuration are being ignored and the Integration Tests are writing into the real database.

Is possible to make the DAL to use H2 configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, seting up H2 configuration for nested projects is very much possible.

The reason I was unable te setup this configuration rigth on the first attempt was because on DAL I have configured multiple data sources, as such the default h2 configuration wouldnt be enought.

So I had to make something like the folloing:

```
first-datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
first-datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
first-datasource.username=sa
first-datasource.password=password

second-datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
second-datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
second-datasource.username=sa
second-datasource.password=password
```